# How to Display Doughnut Chart Using Chart.js in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I'm attempting to incorporate a doughnut chart into my admin panel dashboard using Chart.js, following a YouTube tutorial. However, the chart area on my webpage remains blank, unlike the tutorial's outcome. Below are screenshots illustrating the expected result and my current page's state:

- Expected doughnut chart:

  [image]
- My webpage (chart area is blank to the right):

[image]

Could someone help identify what might be missing or incorrect in my implementation that's preventing the chart from displaying?

**Code:**
I've minimized my code to focus on the relevant parts that should produce the doughnut chart. This includes the HTML structure for the chart container and the JavaScript for initializing the Chart.js doughnut chart. Any assistance in pinpointing the discrepancy or error would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart" id="doughnut-chart">
        <canvas id="doughnut"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript (chart.js):**

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('doughnut').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ['Academic', 'Non-academic', 'Administration', 'Others'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [42, 12, 8, 6],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true
    }
});
```

Comment: You have `ctx` and `myChart` declared twice. Change the name of one of the chart scripts and your charts will work

Comment: No worries! In the future if you sense that you have an issue with your JS, run the entire thing through a validator and it'll catch stuff like this. https://beautifytools.com/javascript-validator.php First error to populate is `'ctx' has already been declared.`

Comment: Going to be closing this as it's basically just a typo and won't be of use to any future visitors.